# Powershell : variable with double quotes not working fine

Tags: powershell, runtime-error, double-quotes

I have a problem: My statement is to disable the licenses for O365 for a user which it requests.

```
 $DisableSStatus1 = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId
 xyzCompany:ENTERPRISEPACK -DisabledPlans
 OFFICESUBSCRIPTION,SHAREPOINTWAC
```

If I use it directly like this the two mentioned licenses get disabled.

But yes the user will have its own choosing of license that it wants to disable. SO, I pass this as a variable

```
 $DisableSStatus1 = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId
 xyzcompany:ENTERPRISEPACK -DisabledPlans $EP and $EP =
 "OFFICESUBSCRIPTION,SHAREPOINTWAC"
```

After running i get the error:

> Unable to assign this license because the license options are invalid

Please tell me what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: It needs to be an array of two strings, not a single string with a comma in it. Try `$EP = "OFFICESUBSCRIPTION","SHAREPOINTWAC"`

Comment: This is what i did just now and it seems to work but the integration team won't pass values like these....like in an array...so any other solution.

Comment: ...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/new-msollicenseoptions?view=azureadps-1.0 - `[-DisabledPlans <System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.String]>]` the argument is not "like an array", it *is* an array. Or at least, as far as it matters it is, it's a list of strings. If the integration team won't use it properly, what hope do you have? Parse whatever input they give and turn it into something usable..

Comment: You can split your string to get an array, Try $EP = "OFFICESUBSCRIPTION,SHAREPOINTWAC" -split ','